# Simple Console Chess Game

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, chess

I'm currently working on a small C++ console game. The first problem which I encountered, is a bad display of chess board (string 8x8 array). But first of all, let me give you a short briefing.

My idea was to treat every single chess figure as a single object - thus both white and black ones has their own instance - for pawn it's 16 instances (equally 8 for white & black), for rook it's 4, etc. etc.

Then I created another class, called *ChessBoard*, which stores informations such as number of killed figures, specific player's result, etc. and is meant to oversee the other classes. Most importantly, it stores mentioned above string array, which contains graphical representation of every figure (*std::string pic* line). Now, going back to the problem: when I try to print out this array in order to check its integrity and order, it reveals that all of its cells are displayed vertically. I wanted to display it in this manner (P fields represents specific figure, an empty field is located lower):

```
***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
* P * * P * * P * * P * * P * * P * * P * * P *
***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
|   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   |
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
```

And that's what actually happens:
[image]

I know that this subject was raised many times on this site, but I tried every possible solution given by other users, but it doesn't work - the only difference is a position of some single signs, but overall array's display is still bad.

Project's dependencies:

**BoardLogic.h -> BoardComponents.h**

**main.cpp -> BoardLogic.cpp -> BoardComponents.cpp**

I'll give you a small view to the project's files.
This is a very beginning of my work, so I only casted Pawn's instances and tried to display them correctly on board.

**BoardComponents.h**

```
#ifndef BOARDCOMPONENTS_H_
#define BOARDCOMPONENTS_H_
#include "BoardLogic.h"
#include <string>

class Pawn {
public:
    bool isAlive;
    std::string pic = "*****\n* P *\n*****";
    struct currentPosition {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    Pawn::currentPosition pPos;
private:

};

class Rook {
public:
    bool isAlive;
    std::string pic = "*****\n* R *\n*****";
    struct currentPosition {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    Rook::currentPosition rPos;
private:

};

class Knight {
public:
    bool isAlive;
    std::string pic = "*****\n* k *\n*****";
    struct currentPosition {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    Knight::currentPosition kPos;
private:

};

class Bishop {
public:
    bool isAlive;
    std::string pic = "*****\n* B *\n*****";
    struct currentPosition {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    Bishop::currentPosition bPos;
private:

};

class Queen {
public:
    bool isAlive;
    std::string pic = "*****\n* Q *\n*****";
    struct currentPosition {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    Queen::currentPosition qPos;
private:

};

class King {
public:
    bool isAlive;
    std::string pic = "*****\n* K *\n*****";
    struct currentPosition {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    King::currentPosition kingPos;
private:

};

class ChessBoard {
public:
    std::string chessBoard[8][8];
    int wChessKilled;
    int bChessKilled;
    int wPlayerResult;
    int bPlayerResult;
    bool winner;
private:

};

#endif
```

**BoardLogic.cpp** - this file creates new instance of the game as well as its component classes

```
#include "BoardLogic.h"
#include "BoardComponents.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void ChessGame::NewGameInstance() {

    ChessBoard * cBoard = new ChessBoard;
    Pawn * wPawn = new Pawn[8];
    Pawn * bPawn = new Pawn[8];
    Rook * wRook = new Rook[2];
    Rook * bRook = new Rook[2];
    Knight * wKnight = new Knight[2];
    Knight * bKnight = new Knight[2];
    Bishop *wBishop = new Bishop[2];
    Bishop *bBishop = new Bishop[2];
    Queen *wQueen = new Queen;
    Queen *bQueen = new Queen;
    King * wKing = new King;
    King *bKing = new King;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            cBoard->chessBoard[i][j] = "-----\n|   |\n-----";
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        wPawn[i].pPos.x = i;
        wPawn[i].pPos.y = 1;
        bPawn[i].pPos.x = i;
        bPawn[i].pPos.y = 6;
        wPawn[i].isAlive = true;
        bPawn[i].isAlive = true;
        cBoard->chessBoard[wPawn[i].pPos.x][wPawn[i].pPos.y] = wPawn[i].pic;
        cBoard->chessBoard[bPawn[i].pPos.x][bPawn[i].pPos.y] = bPawn[i].pic;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
            cout << cBoard->chessBoard[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: A bit offtopic, but have you considered splitting up your chess game into two different parts? I.e. the engine and the UI? There are standard chess protocols that allow your engine to work with other user iterfaces, and other engines to work with your ui. You could even let your engine play against another engine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_engine

Comment: sure, but due to the fact that I want to learn some more advanced programming techniques, I really want to create it from scratch. And yeah, I want to split the program, that's why I use this class system. Ultimately, file "BoardComponents" would store all of chess board's elements (pawns etc), as well as its statistics, and "BoardLogic" would handle in-game events, rules, etc.This kind of solution isn't really special, it's just a self-preservation instinct :P

Answer (score 0):

Your `ChessBoard` has to have the concept of a row and must render all items in the row before moving on to the next row. A collection of strings isn't really ideal.

The fact that you use "\n" inside the render is a problem. You need to draw all the "first lines" of items in the row and then all the second lines and so on. An easy way around this at least to get going would be just use a single char for each piece: 'K', 'Q' ... 'p'.

Don't forget that you still need to draw "something" (empty spaces) for empty positions in each row.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I was suspecting this scenario as well. I'll take a closer look into it later.

EDIT. If I understood correctly, I'm supposed to create a char array for every single object's representation (pawn, rook, empty cell, etc.), and then merge them all in one huge entity (in this case chess board)?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is having a 2D char array (31 * 47). Since every grid is a 3x5 array, the width of the board is 5 * 8 + 7 (gaps in between). The height will be 3 * 8 + 7.

When you want to print the board, you take the pic from the chess piece, split it into 3 lines, then put it on the 2D char array accordingly. After you finish placing the pieces on the board, you can put the entire 2D array in 1 go.

One example on how to place the 3x5 array onto the board array:

```
//row and col are physical position on the board, both ranging from 0 to 7
void PlaceOnBoard(char[][47] board, char[][5] pattern, int row, int col)
{
    int start_row = row * 4;
    int start_col = col * 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            board[start_row + i][start_col + j] = pattern[i][j];

}
```

Another alternative is every time you print out a row in the chess board, you do in 3 iterations, first iteration will print first row of each piece, second iteration will print second row...

Comment: that's what I've already done - now, every single figure (as well as empty cell) has a char[3][5] array with "graphical" representation, which I currently try to inject into bigger char[32][48] array, which is quiet tough, because I can't figure out how to successfully nest for loops (one for filling main "board" array, and one for a specific object).

Comment: Add an example on how to map the piece from physical coordinate to board coordinate

Comment: yeah, it's definitely getting closer. Now I need to adjust it to my existing code. The only problem with your example is that I cannot use it recursively with my target arrays, because they are casted in another function. This is btw. my biggest issue I always encounter during working on structs and arrays - I have no idea how to deal with problem with accessing objects/structures/arrays created in one function, from another) - in most cases using 'return' statement is out of a question due to its nature/type of data.

Comment: If the array is created in another function, there are 2 options: (1) Create it as std::array or std::vector and return the object back. (2) Create it in the dynamic way using pointer and return just the pointer. To be honest, you should hold the big char array inside your chessboard class and only allows modification via your public method, accessing variable from method inside the same class should be really easy and you don't have to pass the array around as well.

Comment: Btw, in my example, the array comes from the caller so there should not be any problem for the caller to access it.

Comment: Btw, if I am going to write this, I will first create a base class called Piece as interface with methods like Pattern (to get the pattern), Type and Color, etc. Then use this base class to be inherited by classes like Rook, Knight, King, Queen, Bishop, Pawn and also Empty piece just to represent empty tile. Then chessboard is simply Piece[8][8]. In your current design, you are going to run into trouble in cases when a pawn managed to reach the opposite end and turn into a different piece type.